# Dropping characters when printing from 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string of characters for which I want to encrypt by loading into a 2D array by rows and then printing the array by column. Such that:

---

### |A|B|

### |C|D|

### |E|

encrypts to "ACEBD".

However I cant seem to be able to avoid dropping characters in the last row in my output getting "ACBD". Any idea how to solve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (handleArguments(args))
        System.out.println("encrypt");


    // get input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String line = input.nextLine();
    // calculate height of the array
    int height = line.length() / width;
    // Add one to height if there's a partial last row
    if (line.length() % width != 0)
        height += 1;

    loadUnloadGrid(line, width, height);
}
static void loadUnloadGrid(String line, int width, int height) {
    // make an empty array
    char grid[][] = new char[height][width];

    // fill the array row by row with character from line

    int charCount = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            // check to make sure accessing past end of the line
            if (charCount < line.length()) {
                grid[r][c] = line.charAt(charCount);
                charCount++;

            }
        }
    }

    // print to standard output the characters in array
    System.out.printf("Grid width %d: \"", width);
    for (int r = 0; r < width; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < height; c++) {
            System.out.print(grid[c][r]);
        }
    }
    // !!Special handling for last row!!
    int longColumn = line.length() % width;
    if (longColumn == 0)
        longColumn = width;

    for (int c = 0; c < longColumn; c++) {
        System.out.print(grid[height - 1][c]);
    }
    System.out.println();



}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in an IDE debugger? That is the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the rows before you loop the columns, i.e., just the way you usually don't do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
         // prints columns before rows
    }
}
```

However, be aware that you cannot check whether one row has less columns than another within the loop. Usually `array[i].length` avoids any NPEs. In this case you might want to define a check whether the array at row `j` even has column `i`. This could be done within the second loop by checking:

```
if (array[j].length > i)
    // System.out.println(...);
else
    break;
```

Edit: I see your loop should be working correctly. Most likely `height` is only `1` instead of `2` and thus, the last row gets cut off. My code as it is works for your input and your loop should be working the same way. Try to print `height` and check if it is correct or debug your program and go through it step by step.